# Is there any standard for naming controllers and partial files with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have been using the following:

```
file /content/app/admin/controllers/content-controller.js

angular.module('admin').controller('AdminContentController',  

file /content/app/home/partials/overviewItem.html
```

I copied the idea of a hyphen in the name of the controller but now I am not sure if it is needed. I'd like some suggestions maybe it's better to just call the file content.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a discussion here on the topic, but there's not a standard way for naming.

I would look at the [ng-boilerplate kickstarter](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate) in github or [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) for some reasonable ways of naming.

As long as you are consistent within your app (naming, coding, styling, etc) then that should be the main driver.